# Unir elementos de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, tuplas

Tengo este código, al unir los elementos en la lista se unen de esta forma
ej: (['I25', 'I21', 'I20', 'I18', 'I22'], ['G53', 'G48', 'G56', 'G58', 'G60'], ['N35', 'N42', 'N40', 'N39'], ['O69', 'O63', 'O75', 'O74', 'O61'], ['B9', 'B3', 'B13', 'B4', 'B8'])

me gustaría saber como puedo unir y mezclar los elementos para que salgan de esta forma
ej: ('I25', G53', 'I21', O69','B3' 'I20', 'N39',............)

Gracias :)

```
from random import shuffle

balotas = ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "B9", "B10", "B11", "B12", "B13",
          "B14", "B15","I16", "I17", "I18", "I19", "I20", "I21", "I22", "I23", "I24", "I25",
          "I26", "I27", "I28", "I29", "I30", "N31", "N32", "N33", "N34", "N35", "N36", "N37",
          "N38", "N39", "N40", "N41", "N42", "N43", "N44", "N45", "G46", "G47", "G48", "G49", "G50", "G51", "G52", "G53",
          "G54", "G56", "G57", "G58", "G59", "G60", "O61", "O62", "O63", "O64", "O65", "O66", "O67",
          "O68", "O69", "O70", "O71", "O72", "O73", "O74", "O75"]
shuffle(balotas)  #mezcla las balotas
balotera = []

B= [ s for s in balotas if "B" in s]  #Busca a letra determinada en la lista mezclada
balotera.append(B[0:5])  #Añade la letra a la lista

I = [ s for s in balotas if "I" in s]
balotera.append(I[0:5])

N = [ s for s in balotas if "N" in s]
balotera.append(N[0:4])

G = [ s for s in balotas if "G" in s]
balotera.append(G[0:5])

O = [ s for s in balotas if "O" in s]
balotera.append(O[0:5])



balotas_minimas=(print(tuple(balotera)))    ##convierte la lista a tupla y la muestra
```

Comment: Disculpa, no había leído bien. De cualquier forma, ¿Que criterio sigue esa salida? ¿Tomar simplemente 7 elementos aleatorios de diferentes letras? ¿Hacer una tupla con los todos los elementos aleatorizados? Define "esta forma" con palabras porque no queda claro.

Comment: Disculpa y yo olvidé añadir los puntos suspensivos al final, sólo debo unir y mezclar los elementos que devuelve la lista balotera, ya que en este momento las devuelve de forma ordenada y separada por grupos así [B][I][N][G][O] . necesito que los devuelva de forma aleatoria, por ejemplo, (B,N,G,G,I,O....) , no sé si me hago entender @JaimeMenéndez

Comment: Si entendí bien tienes una lista de lista de listas `[[B][I][N][G][O]]` y quieres unir todos los elementos de las listas en una tupla y desordenar los elementos. ¿Es eso?

Comment: Es correcto @JaimeMenéndez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes desempaquetar los elementos de `balotera` en una tupla usando el operador `*` aplicado sobre cada elemento de dicha lista. Dado que la lista se compone de 5 elementos, podrías hacerlo directamente así:

```py
balotera_tupla = (*balotera[0], *balotera[1], *balotera[2], *balotera[3], *balotera[4])
print(balotera_tupla)
```

No puedes añadir elementos a una tupla de forma dinámica, ya que las tuplas son inmutables.

Otra forma sería crear una lista plana a partir de tu lista de `balotera`:

```py
balotera_flat = [item for balota in balotera for item in balota]
balotera_tupla = tuple(balotera_flat)
print(balotera_tuple)
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias